# Python hex variable assignment

Tags: python-2.7

I'm using a variable to store data that gets sent by a socket. When I assign it in my program it works but when I read it from a file it is treated as a string.

Example:

```
data = '\x31\x32\x33'

print data
```

Outputs

```
123   # <--- this is the result I want when I read from a file to assign data


f = open('datafile')  <--- datafile contains \x31\x32\x33 on one line

data = f.readline()

print data
```

Outputs

```
\x31\x32\x33  # <--- wanted it to print 123, not \x31\x32\x33.
```

Comment: How are you saving that data to the file. Also, what does it say when you do `len(data)` ?

Comment: You seem to have created the file containing 6 characters, and not 3 bytes as you expected.

Comment: You **shouldn't** use it, but `print(eval("'" + data + "'"))` would do it.

Comment: The data is coming from a wireshark export as a C array like char peer0_0[] = {0x10, 0x00, 0x0b}. I'm cleaning it up into the format that seems to work for python '\x10\x00\x0b'which works in my first example, but I want to get the same result when I read from a file.

Comment: Tried to simplify by showing an example using print. When I use it in s.send(data) in the first example it send the hex bytes 313233, which I want, in the second example it sends 5c7833315c7833325c783333

Comment: Thanks all for the replies! I can control how the file is formatted so I stripped out all the \x and used decode() as a couple here recommended. That did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python the string `'\x31\x32\x33'` is actually only three characters `'\x31'` is the character with ordinal 0x31 (49), so `'\x31'` is equivalent to `'1'`.  It sounds like your file actually contains the 12 characters `\x31\x32\x33`, which is equivalent to the Python string `'\\x31\\x32\\x33'`, where the escaped backslashes represent a single backslash character (this can also be represented with the raw string literal `r'\x31\x32\x33'`).

If you really are sure that this data should be `'123'`, then you need to look at how that file is being written.  If that is something you can control then you should address it there so that you don't end up with data consisting of several bytes representing hex escapes.

It is also possible that whatever is writing this data is already using some data-interchange format (similar to JSON), in which case you don't need to change how it is written, you just need to use a decoder for that data-interchange format (like `json.loads()`, but this isn't JSON).

If somehow neither of the above are really what you want, and you just want to figure out how to convert a string like `r'\x31\x32\x33'` to `'123'` in Python, here is how you can do that:

```
>>> r'\x31\x32\x33'.decode('string_escape')
'123'
```

Or in Python 3.x:

```
>>> br'\x31\x32\x33'.decode('unicode_escape')
'123'
```

**edit:** Based on comments it looks like you are actually getting hex strings like `'313233'`, to convert a string like that to `'123'` you can decode using hex:

```
>>> '313233'.decode('hex')
'123'
```

Or on Python 3.x:

```
>>> bytes.fromhex('313233').decode('utf-8')
'123'
```

Comment: Thanks! I can control how the file is formatted so I stripped out all the \x and used decode. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you do a conversion from a string to an int, you can specify the base of the numbers in the string:

```
>>> print int("31", 16)
49

>>> chr(49)
'1'
```

So you should be able to just parse the hex values out of your file and individually convert them to chars.

Comment: That one-step conversion doesn't work. Just print out x after you assign it, and you'll see the string '123AU'. Splitting it on a substring that doesn't occur will produce a list containing just the original string.

Comment: yeah if you assign with x = r"\x31\x32\x33\x41\x55" which is the equivalent of what he is reading in, this doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

As stated you are doing post processing, it would be easier to handle if the text was "313233"
you would then be able to use

```
data = "313233"    
print data.decode("hex") # this will print '123'
```

As stated in comments this is for python 2.7, and is deprecated in 3.3. However unless this question is mis-tagged, this will work.

Comment: he called out he's using python 2.7 in his tags

Answer (score 0):

I might have violated many programming standards here, but the following code works for the given situation

```
with open('datafile') as f:
    data=f.read()
data=data.lstrip('\\x') #strips the leftmost '\x' so that now string 'data' contains numbers saperated by '\x'
data=data.strip().split('\\x') #now data contains list of numbers
s=''
for d in data:
    s+=chr(int(d,16)) #this converts hex ascii values to respective characters and concatenate to 's'
print s
```