# Declaring a variable as hex in Python

Tags: python, variables, type-conversion, hex

I have a variable

```
s=64
```

This variable is in hex. But Python takes it as decimal. How do I declare it as a hex variable?

I know to declare something as hex, we use

```
s=0x64
```

But I have only

```
s=64
```

How can I go about this?

Comment: Do you want your s variable will remain the same as hex?

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465969/python-hex-variable-assignment?rq=1) solution

Comment: **But I have only  s=64**, what do you mean you only have `s=64`?

Comment: `64` is the number 64 in decimal. `0x64` is the number 100 in hexadecimal. `0x40` is the number 64 in hexadecimal. Is any of these what you want? If not, what else do you want?

Comment: What is the problem here? You use base 16 with `0x` as you said and when you do that you declare the number in hex. Do you want to also print the number in hex?  Please be more clear.

Comment: @Countour-Integral Yes I want to print in hex. The issue is that: s=64 is decimal. I want to use 64 in hex such that s=64 in hex. So that when I further convert it to decimal, I get 100.

I was somehow able to achieve this. But the next problem arises when s=B0, how do i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number `64` in hex (base 16) is `100`. To achieve you answer, you should use a combination of [hex()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#hex), [int()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#int) and [str()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#func-str)
If you start with `s = 64` and you want to end up with `s = 100` which is the decimal value of `0x64`, consider this code:

```
s = 64
s = int(str(s), 16)
```

If you want something else, please clarify what, and note that you can try to achieve it yourself with some combination of hex(), int() and str()

Comment: Hi. I have tried this and it works. But when I get a value s=B0 then it shows an error.

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, `64` is an integer number, when you supply `s=B0` it is no longer an integer and in fact you can't just write `s = B0` in python, it will result in a NameError. Please be more specific about how you declare the value, and what do you want the result to be. And one again, it is just some combination of hex() str() and int(). If you give me more details I can help you get your answer, Or you can just play it with youself, Mabye read the documentation in the links I provided and understand those functions.

Comment: You are correct. The situation is that I am extracting values from a longer variable that is transmitted from the system. For e.g. 62 1A 14 B0 00 00 00 00. I get this value as a response from the system

I want to extract the B0 from this and work on it as an integer (176).

Comment: In what type this input come in? A String? If the answer is yes, then just `s = (s, 16)` will result in `s => 176`.

Comment: The above statement did not work. But I tried s=int (s,16), and it worked thanks!

Comment: Haha yeah I forgot the 'int' there :) Happy this worked out!

Answer (score 2):

I think that is something missing in your code theory or question.

One thing is the **value** and one another is **presentation (interpretation)**.
So the value is 100 (decimal), but it can be seen (**converted**) as a decimal or hexadecimal (or whatever you like):

```
>>> s=0x64
>>> s
100
>>> hex(s)
'0x64'
>>> h = int(str(0x64), 16)
>>> h
256
```

Python stores an integer as a decimal (by default). If you want to have a number that acts as a hexadecimal you should code your own class and use the conversion routines I showed above.